# Granting administrative consent

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm exploring accessing mail (and sending mail) on behalf of other users. I have read about the graph api which would allow me also to handle chat messages later on.

I wanted to start implementing this with my personal account (@outlook.com) and followed basically this tutorial: https://cmatskas.com/create-a-net-core-deamon-app-that-calls-msgraph-with-a-certificate/ (this seems to be the same as the walkthrough in the portal)

I found questions and answers (like [Microsoft Graph to send mail with Client Credential Flow (application permission) and personal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426179/microsoft-graph-to-send-mail-with-client-credential-flow-application-permission)) but I do want to create a daemon app which seems not to work with a personal account (which makes sense because I could read Microsoft's end user customers data).

Furthermore, when trying to create such an app there is the following warning:

[image: Warning about verified publishers]

If I would create a development env for this I am still now working at a verified publisher, so I cannot develop an application to see if it fits our needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have a developer sandbox from Microsoft for that purpose.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program-get-started for information on this